# How to redirect and in the same time allow any files in directory .htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, redirect

currently, I've used this code in my htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301] 
# Allow any files or directories that exist to be displayed directly
RewriteCond ${REQUEST_URI} ^.+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.(gif|jpe?g|png|js|css|swf|php|ico|txt|pdf|xml)$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

Options -Indexes
```

This will hide my directory and let me view my file, but how to put together redirect (code below) into above code?

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.nextdomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.nextdomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Do the `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on` and associated `RewriteRule` first, then the new one, then the others.  This will ensure that 1) forces https.  2) forces site name.  3) the rest.  Using the `[L]` option ensures that once a match if found (top to bottom), it stops there and does not apply the following rules.

Answer (score 0):

Okay here the answers after get guide from @Nic3500

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.nextdomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.nextdomain.com/$1 [L]
# Allow any files or directories that exist to be displayed directly
RewriteCond ${REQUEST_URI} ^.+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.(gif|jpe?g|png|js|css|swf|php|ico|txt|pdf|xml)$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
```